# Finding all stationary point in a specific interval

Tags: functions, derivatives

Let's say I have $f(x) = x + cos(x)$, a continous and differentiable function:

[image]

When I try to find a stationary point with 0 = f'(x), I get the first stationary point only: on (1.157, f(1.157)). How can I find all other stationary points? E.g: in a specific interval [10,22]?

Comment: What is your method to solve the equation $1-\sin x=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that

$$f'(x)=1-\sin x=0\iff \sin x=1\iff x=\frac\pi2+2n\pi\;,\;\;n\in\Bbb Z$$

Well, now check which ones of the above points lay on $\;[10,22]\;$ ...

Comment: ok, thank you very much. Could you please tell me how someone would efficiently proceed from that point on with those two equations?

Comment: @steven2005 What two equations? I only see one: a simple trigonometric equation $\;f'(x)=0\;$ ...and that's all. Now you must solve a double inequality: $$10\le\frac\pi3+2n\pi\le22\iff10-\frac\pi2\le2n\pi\le22-\frac\pi2\iff\frac5\pi-\frac14\le n\le\frac{11}\pi-\frac14$$ and you need all natural numbers that fulfill the above. So now eavluate: $\;\frac5\pi-\frac14\approx 1.3\le n\le3.2\approx\frac{11}\pi-\frac14\implies n=2,3...\;$